# SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(Rect dirty)

Tags: android, android-animation

I am drawing [android.graphics.Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) to [android.graphics.Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) via [SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(Rect dirty)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas(android.graphics.Rect)).

I am specifying the dirty Rect to avoid overdraw and flicker.

The problem is that regardless of the path's line width, all pixels of the Rect are filled with the Path's Paint. Am I misunderstanding the usage of the dirty Rect?